# Subversion HTTP file link does not respect peg revision, any workaround?

Tags: svn

The problem is: When visiting a SVN directory via web browsers with `?p=NNN` option, it lists files at that revision as desired. However, the file link given by the Web server does not have `?p=NNN` appended so may result in broken link, or, even worse, user unconciously fetching inconsistent or undesired versions as time goes by.

`?p=NNN` is a great feature which lets us have a permanent link to a historical file and I love it. Hope there is a solution or workaround for this issue.

[image]

[[ Detail Added ]]

SVN server env:

- Windows Server 2003 SP3
- SVN and apache http server is from CollabNet, installer named CollabNetSubversion-server-1.6.4-1.win32.exe . Httpd.exe version 2.2.11 .
- svn-related configuration in httpd.conf is like:

-

```
<Location /svnreps/WebApps/>
  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath D:/SvnReps/WebApps
  AuthzSVNAccessFile D:/SvnReps/WebApps/svn-authz-file

  Satisfy Any
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: hmm this is strange.. It works on my machine..can you post details on server-OS,apache version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked Apache's SVN repo with a peg revision:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/?p=999999

It does show `?p=999999` for each file/dir link on the webpage.

Then, I tried Collabnet Subversion Edge 2.3.0 (svn 1.7.3, Feb 2012). Well, good, peg revision does appear on all links.

So, perhaps that is a problem for some older Subversion version.

[image]

On Sourceforge: https://gnumakeuniproc.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gnumakeuniproc/trunk/?p=999 (Subversion 1.6.9, also does well)

[2012-09-03] **SOLUTION FOUND**

Now, I almost confirm that it is due to an old subversion version. I upgrade my the problem Apache+SVN instance to 1.7.6 from CollabNet. http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion . Now I got desired result.

I use the **Subversion 1.7.6 + Apache Server (Windows 32-bit)** package, and it offers to upgrade my existing server. I accept the upgrade, and httpd.conf is not changed during the upgrade.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Peter Parker here on this one, your problem seems to work with my version of SVN. You could also try this URL format instead to see if this works instead, it's the URL format that I have used often in the past

`<REPO_URL>/!svn/bc/<REVISION_NUMBER>/<FILE_LOCATION>`

Example

```
http://svnbox/repository/!svn/bc/13/trunk/my_file
```

This works with both files and directories.

Having said this, I would have thought it would retrieve the same output as the `?p=` feature which in your case doesn't work. Anyhow, it's worth a shot!

**EXAMPLE**

```
$ svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/site/trunk/content/index.mdtext
Path: index.mdtext
Name: index.mdtext
URL: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/site/trunk/content/index.mdtext
Repository Root: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
Repository UUID: 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
Revision: 1435013
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: jim
Last Changed Rev: 1384287
Last Changed Date: 2012-09-13 04:51:01 -0700 (Thu, 13 Sep 2012)
```

To grab revision 1435013 by name:

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/!svn/bc/1435013/httpd/site/trunk/content/index.mdtext

Comment: Thank you, your trick works great for that problem svn server instance.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the slash at the end.

So instead of `https://example.com/svn/folder/?p=9`

use the url `https://example.com/svn/folder?p=9`

Comment: Sorry, the same result on my SVN server.